# jQuery tagit delete clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using jQuery tagit..

In the right corner there is a little close button, to delete the tags.

My question now is, IS there a possible way to delete the tags just på clicking them instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to remove 'x' from a close element: go to 487. line of tagit.js, and remove x, like this:

```
 + '<div class="tagit-label">' + newTag.label + '</div>' + '<a class="tagit-close"> </a></li>');
```

Then, in css file of theme you are using, modify tagit-close class:

For simple blue theme, e.g. tagit-simple-blue.css:

```
 ul.tagit li.tagit-choice a.tagit-close {
        /* color: #777777;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        outline: medium none;
        padding: 2px 0 2px 3px;
        text-decoration: none;


       top: 0;
        right: 3px;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);*/
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
display: block;
    }
```